# Logic to hide opened sub menu on click elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Suppose user goes to a ecommerce site and clicks on products, there is a submenu which drops down. What logic to write to ensure that when user clicks on any other blank space(or elements) that submenu is hidden back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this js fiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/H3Vnw/3/

Here is the java script code:-

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $('.dropdown-menu');

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});


$('.comment').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

If we click on the comment we can get drop menu if we click else where the drop menu will be hidden!

Hope this helps!

Comment: i think what you have answered is pretty much right. If you  can explain few queries - why use mouseup, and not click? and if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) what does this line mean?

Comment: @sahilsharma if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) this part will whether we click on the target or not if length =0 means we are not clicking on the target that means we have to hide it! That's hw it works!

Comment: @sahilsharma I have just given u the logic since u have asked the same! U can change mouseup to click it won't create any problem!

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: something that listens to anything but the submenu click, and closes it.

```
// assumption: submenu has open() and close() functions
submenu.open();
var listener = document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // TODO: how to check if click is on submenu?
    if (e.target != submenu) { 
       submenu.close(); 
       document.removeEventListener('click', listener);
    }
});
```